# ASP.NET forcing page reload and effecting jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am using jQuery for some functionality within my ASP.NET application, however every time a jQuery event is triggered the results display for a second but the page then refreshes. The code will take what the user selects from an select box and put it into a text box, the thing is it works in chrome but for the life of me I cannot get it working in firefox. I need this to work in fixfox as it will be getting in it.

How could I get this to work in firefox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#mybkng').hide();
        $('#props').click(getProp);
    });

    function getProp() {
        var prop = $(this).val();
        $('#select').click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#mybkng').show();
            $('#theproperty').val(prop);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated this has been driving me nuts. Also would it be possible to do this with VB?

Comment: I assume you're using webforms and the `#props` button is bound server side or has the `runat="server"` attribute specified?

Comment: within the mybkng div there are run at server tag will this effect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the function call use return before the function call on the button.
 In the function

```
function getProp() {
    var prop = $(this).val();
    $('#select').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#mybkng').show();
        $('#theproperty').val(prop);
    });
    return false
}
```

and where ever you are calling use return before it as follows

```
   OnClientClick="return getProp();"
```